# How do I repair this patio wall?

Tags: concrete, exterior, stucco, retaining-wall

My HOA doesn't want to do it and I need to sell this condo. Not sure how to tell if it is stucco or concrete. I have lots of experience with drywall repair, but never done this on the outside. What materials would be used? I'm thinking of just caulking/painting the cracks and patching the bad spot with stucco repair?

[image: cracks on exterior]
[image: material is missing completely here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be stucco or cement, cement's just a little stronger. Some people just peel off the big pieces and glue them back on with Masonry Adhesive to then caulk and paint everything...pretty much a requirement so repairs aren't obvious. Here are some examples of how quite easy it is https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=stucco+a+block+wall

Or, you can screw the popped and pulled away pieces back to flat to then caulk and paint. Otherwise, it's actually much more forgiving than doing deep joint compound, keep laying it on in one-application, in this case, until you're flush. But, no shame in blowing $200 for a mason to do it if you don't have the time or experience and don't want the mess.